# How to run multiple tests using a Before hook in cypress?

Tags: cypress, hook

I am trying to run multiple tests in Cypress. I created a separat file in `/support` folder, named ```steps.js`` where I am using my variables from a fixture file

**steps.js**

```
import * as Credentials from "../fixtures/login"

before(function () {
    cy.visit("")
    cy.contains("a", "Login").click()
    cy.get("#id_username").type(Credentials.username)
    cy.get("#id_password").type(Credentials.password)
    cy.get("[type='submit']").click()

})
```

And then I created a file named `addCreation.cy.js` where I want a user to add a creation in the website. The `addCreation.cy.js` file looks like this:

```
import "../support/steps"

describe('Add Personal Creation to website', () => {

    it('should click on Creations link', () => {
        cy.contains("a", "Creations")
          .click()
        cy.url().should('include','/blog/')
    })

    it('should open new creation page', () => {
        cy.url().should('include','/blog/')
        cy.get("[type='submit']").click()
        cy.url().should('include', '/blog/blog/new/')
        cy.get('legend')
          .should('have.text', 'Name your creation here:')
    })
       
 })
```

So I am using `before` hook. My question is how can I run the tests in order without having to create only one single `it` step. It is possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the `before` hook needs to be repeated for every test. That's because the test runner clears such things as URL and stored tokens for log in.

If you change the hook to `beforeEach` you should remove your problem

```js
beforeEach(function () {
    cy.visit("")
    cy.contains("a", "Login").click()
    cy.get("#id_username").type(Credentials.username)
    cy.get("#id_password").type(Credentials.password)
    cy.get("[type='submit']").click()

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run tests in order by using the option `testIsolation`, keeping it `false` at the `describe` level.

```
describe('Example', {testIsolation : false} , () => {
}
```

For more details [Read the Official Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation).